# Express 'green pepper' as one word

Tags: word-usage, expressions

The noun-phrase "Green pepper" has two words, but I need it considered as one word

In this case, *Consider it as a word* Is the proper expression?

Comment: I can hardly understand your question. Do you want a one-word synonym for "green pepper"?

Comment: 'Green pepper' is not a sentence. it's an adjective & a noun, or  a noun-phrase. You could call it a bell-pepper or a capsicum, but it would still need 'green' to differentiate it from any other colour/variety.

Comment: I'm learning the English language. But basically I mean expression: Consider it as a word.
_Green pepper_ could be any sentence with 2 words.

Comment: …which brings us back to point one - it's not a sentence.

Comment: hmmm... "[green pepper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/green-pepper)" can be considered as one word, that is, as a compound word (don't worry about the space inbetween). But it is still not clear what you are asking.

Comment: To "consider something as a word" is a proper expression. To "consider it as a word" is a proper expression. And you can consider "green pepper" to be one compound word.

Comment: I think you are not asking about green peppers, but instead about how to discuss single vs. multiple words, right?  You don't care about peppers at  all?  If that is correct, I still don't know if you want to ask us how to tell someone to  _treat_ two words as if they were one, or to ask someone for a single word equivalent for multiple words.  (E.g. "Alphabetize and count the number of words in your article, but when you do so, treat the phrase_Green Peppers_ as a single word."  Compare that with "Q: Is there a single word that means the same thing as _male chicken?"_ )

Comment: I don't think it should be closed, since the OP was satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *express something as one word* is the proper expression.

You need "[green pepper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/green-pepper)" **expressed** as one word? Is that it? Well, technically it is one word. It is one (compound) word, like 'attorney general'. It does not matter if there is a space in-between the two parts of the compound word.

Synonyms include

[sweet pepper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sweet-pepper)

[bell pepper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bell-pepper?q=bell%20pepper)

[Capiscum](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/capsicum) can refer to both 'green peppers' and '[chili peppers](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/chilli?q=chili%20pepper)', which are not, believe me, not the same thing! 'Chili peppers' are very spicy.

Comment: Well, I still don't know exactly *what* you needed... :)  But, yeah, 'green pepper' is a word.

Comment: _To "consider something as a word" is a proper expression. To "consider it as a word" is a proper expression. And you can consider "green pepper" to be one compound word._ 
That's what I wanted to know, but because of my poor English skills did not know explain.

Comment: I'm creating a list of fruits and vegetables, but I found this problem that some are as you say: compounds words.

Comment: @pazzo I can already add a better answer: *Consider it as a word!* Re: OK!

Comment: None of those are really synonyms.  Bell peppers come in many colors: red, yellow, orange, purple, even nearly brown/black, as well as green.  Green peppers are not necessarily sweet: jalapenos are green, as are many other hot peppers, and in Mexican cuisine chile verde can be hotter than chile colorado.

Comment: @RobinPlotnik For a list of fruits and vegetables, any of these compound words will do: green peppers, bell peppers, sweet peppers... I have linked to each of their definitions in my answer. I don't know why there is -2 on downvotes, yet no one bothers to write a better answer. I am just trying to help you out. I think others are criticizing but contributing nothing...

Comment: I may not be a native speaker, but I have very high marks in botany, so I know my peppers. I can competently say that this a great answer that matches the OP's needs. Even though the question was not clearly phrased, it was asked to the best of OP's abilities (which the OP politely explained) and it was a noble and successful endeavour to answer it and help the OP. After all, helping is what stack exchange is about, isn't it? (As for the trolls who downvote perfectly good answers without leaving a constructive comment - something should be done about this, but this is a question for meta.)

Comment: @jamesqf Anyone who bothers to click a few times and see the definitions provided in the answer can see that the words listed as synonyms are synonyms in terms of English language. Had the OP wanted a culinary or a plant systematics and taxonomy answer, they probably would have posted this question on another stack exchange website, right?

Comment: @Lucky: The OP does not (or did not at the time I wrote the comment) explain exactly what s/he is looking for.  Also, the links may be to the OED, but that doesn't stop them from being wrong as far as American usage goes.  (Or perhaps I should say usage in the western US, where we perhaps have a wider variety of peppers than are available elsewhere.)